# How to handle horizontally uneven navigation in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm redoing a site for a friend and I was wondering what the best practice would be for doing 
horizontally uneven navigation:

http://www.littlebirddesignstudios.com/

My idea was to just do 4 divs with varying heights but I was wondering how other people would handle this same problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CSS positioning

Ordinarily I'd recommend floating the elements in a horizontal nav bar. But in a case like this, if the navigation area has a fixed height and the content won't change, CSS positioning might be the best fit. That allows you to easily control the exact placement of the nav elements.

Give the nav container `position: relative` and a fixed height, and give the nav elements `position: absolute` and set the values for `left` and `top` as needed.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/N88HT/1/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="design"><a href="#">Design</a></li>
    <li class="services"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li class="bio"><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    ...
}
.nav li {
    position: absolute;
}
.nav li.design   {left: 20px;  top: 40px;}
.nav li.services {left: 160px; top: 50px;}
.nav li.bio      {left: 340px; top: 20px;}
.nav li.contact  {left: 450px; top: 60px;}

.nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 46px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't been on here in a while.  This is excellent and perfect solution. I appreciate it. Sorry for the props delay.